# Un visitor(Patron de diseño) puede modificar atributos de una clase hija de un ConcreteElement abstracto?

Tags: java, patrones-de-diseño

Tengo las interfaces:

```
public interface IVisitado {
    public void Aceptar (IVisitante Visitante);
}
public interface IVisitante {
    public void VisitarA (IVisitado Visitado); //(EnemigoConcreto Visitado)   
}
```

Y las implementan

```
public abstract class EnemigoConcreto implements IVisitado, IEnemigo {
    int HP;
    int MP;
    int Ataque;
    int Defensa;
    int Recompensa; 
    boolean Estado;     
}

public class VisitanteJefe implements IVisitante{

    @Override
    public void VisitarA(IVisitante Visitante){ //(EnemigoConcreto Visitante)
        Visitante.Recompensa *= 10;
    }
```

¿Es posible modificar un atributo de alguna clase hija de EnemigoConcreto por medio del VisitanteJefe manteniendo los parametros de `(IVisitante Visitante)` y no con los parametros que estan en comentario?, Si dejo el codigo tal cual esta no funciona cuando intento acceder al parametro recompensa `Visitante.Recompensa *= 10;`

Comment: Fijate que ahí tal y así como está planteado, estas rompiendo el encapsulamiento, estás tratando de acceder al estado de **Recompensa** y modificarlo sin utilizar las operaciones especifias de ese objeto. Deberías contar con un `setRecompensa(int recompensa)` o un `incrementarRecompensa()`

Comment: @andres Creo que hay un pequeño problema en la semántica, porque en realidad si estás utilizando las operaciones específicas del objeto, pero no las de la Interfaz. Pero de cualquier forma, creo que podrías escribir tu comentario como respuesta para que Adrian la acepte ;)